# How do I list print out all the keys currently stored in my HashMap mapping people to their addresses

Tags: java, hashmap, keyset

How do I list print out all the keys currently stored in my HashMap mapping people to their addresses.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MapTester
{
private HashMap<String, String> addressBook = new HashMap<String, String> ();
private String name;
private String address;

public MapTester()
{
    addressBook.put("Zoe", "9 Applebury Street");
    addressBook.put("Mum", "72 Cherry Tree Drive");
    addressBook.put("Dad", "6 Windsor Avenue");        
}    


/**
 * Input the name and address
 */
public void enterContact(String name, String address)
{       
    addressBook.put(name, address);
}

/**
 * Lookup a contact's name from their address.
 */
public String lookupNumber(String name) 
{          
  name = name;  
  return addressBook.get(name);
}  

public void keySet()
{
   for (String contacts : addressBook)
    {
     System.out.println(contacts);
    }
}
}
```

This is what i've attempted so far and know I need to use the keySet method but am unsure how to apply it.

Comment: where have you declared your "phoneBook" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the following
1) Use the [keySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29)

```
    Set keys = addressBook.keySet();
    for (Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        String key = (String) i.next();
        String value = (String) addressBook.get(key);
        System.out.println("key=" + key + ", value=" + value);
    }
```

or use the Hashmap [values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29) method which returns a Collection view of the values contained in the map

```
    for (String value : addressBook.values()) {
    System.out.println("value=" + value);
    }
```

or directly print the collection returned by [values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29) using [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

```
    System.out.println("addressBook.values =" + Arrays.asList(addressBook.values()));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : addressBook .entrySet()) {
   System.out.println("key=" + entry.getKey() + ", value=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

or

```
Set<String> keys = addressBook.keySet(); // for key set
Iterator iterator=keys.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Comment: OP wants to use keySet

Answer (score 1):

A hashmap has a method keySet
which will return a Set of keys

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet()

In your case

```
Set<String> keys = addressBook.keySet();

 for (String key : keys) {
    System.out.println (key);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over all the keys of your `phoneBook` and get their corresponding address from the `addressBook`.

```
for (String key : phoneBook.keySet()) {
   System.out.println("name=" + key + ", address=" + addressBook.get(key));
}
```